# Is there anyway i can update a firestore document automatically even if app is closed, is there a listeener or something

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a firestore and project that needs to be updated automatically without user interaction but i do not know how to go about it, any help would be appreciated. take a look at the json to understand better

```js
const party =  {
 id: 'bgvrfhbhgnhs',
  isPrivate: 'true',
  isStarted: false,
  created_At: '2021-12-26T05:20:29.000Z',
   start_date: '2021-12-26T02:00:56.000Z'
   
}
```

I want to update the isStarted field to true once the current time is equal to `start_date`

Comment: What does it mean when you say - Google Billing Service won't accept my card ? Can you share some more details about the difficulty you are facing while activating billing for your project. Because the recommended way to do the task you are looking for is to do it using the [Firebase Scheduled Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need ***Firebase Cloud Function***, although I don't understand exactly what you mean.
With ***Cloud Functions***, you can automatically run (add, delete, update, everything) codes on ***Google's Servers*** without the need for application and user interaction.
For example, in accordance with your example, it can automatically set **`"isStarted"`** to true when it hits the **`"start_date"`** time. If you want to code a system that does not require user interaction and should work automatically, you should definitely use ***Cloud Functions***. Otherwise, you cannot do this on the application side.

For more info visit [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)

Comment: Oh, I sure saw cloud functions and checked the documentation, but what’s pissing is that you can only trigger a cloud function inky if a document is updated

Comment: but not when the document is updated (created, deleted), also crown operations can be created. (For example, let it run at 12 o'clock every day, run every 1 minute, and.s). It can also be run with http request (like sending an api query). and there are many different triggering methods like this.

Comment: If we continue with your example, you can check the information in the firestore every 1 minute (or 5-10 minutes). set "isStarted" to true if "start_date" is less than the current date. it will do this according to the time you set automatically with the crown process.

Comment: Here Info Schedular Operations: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

Comment: I tried cloud functions but I don’t know why firebase is not accepting my card, I don’t know if there are any other alternatives to google cloud functions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to find a workaround to updating my documents automatically without user interaction since the google billing service won’t accept my card to enable cloud functions for my project, I tried what I could to make my code work and I don’t know if other peeps would follow my idea or if my idea would solve similar issues.

What I did was that in my nextjs file I created an API endpoint to fetch and update documents after installing the firebase admin SDK,  so I fetched all documents and converted all start_date fields in each document to time and checked for documents whose start date is less than or equal to current date, so after getting the document, I ran a firestore function to Update the document.

Tho this will only run when you make a request to my domain.com/api/update-parties and never run again

In other to make it run at scheduled intervals, I signed up for a free tier account at https://www.easycron.com  and added my API endpoint to EASYCRON to make requests to my endpoint at a minute interval, so when the request hits my endpoint, it runs my code like other serverless functions. Easy peezy.